# Who took care of Naruto as a baby and young child?

Tags: anime, manga, naruto

While we know that the Third Hokage, Lord Sarutobi, essentially saw to Naruto's basic needs,to my knowledge, it's never clearly stated *who* (as in what character or characters, in manga) **took actual care of him** from the time he was born, up to entering the Ninja academy. Yes, we got that he lived by himself from the time he was a kid, and ninja children are largely self sufficient... but *practically* speaking, he was a **total newborn** when his parents died.

[image]

As the story goes, whereas Minato (his father, the Hokage that died protecting the village) wanted the sealing of the Kyuubi within Naruto to be seen by the village as a heroic sacrifice, the collective fear and anger over the village's destruction *instead* just had people view him as a straight up *monster.* To make matters worse, the Third kept his parentage secret; while practical in *one* sense (this anonymity gave a level of protection, as no vengeful enemies came hunting for the 4th Hokage's now defenseless kid), it not only left Naruto parentless, but people only viewed this kid as a reminder of the "beast" that slew their beloved former champion, adding *another* layer of disdain to him.

As such, the kid was feared, if not full on *shunned and reviled.**

[image]

**Keep in Mind:** Naruto was a total innocent, at this point. He himself had *done* nothing; both his parents had died on the night he was born; had no memory of his folks, having only *one moment* with his mother he wouldn't even remember...

[image]

Arguably, Jiraiya (his official god father) could have been seing about him... but the kid didn't even *meet* his God Dad until he was 10 years old...and then *he* would be taken from him too, 5 years later. Again, I get that this was partly done for safety (Jiraiya couldn't be doing his whole "dangerous information gathering" and technique refining while caring for a baby, so needed the boy to be capable of basic skills before he took him on). Still....

[image]

Basically, the three people who would have loved him most were taken out of Naruto's life and unknown to him until his middle teens.

[image]

By contrast, we know that Gaara (who had a similar bad treatment experience as a Jinchuriki), at least had his aunt/uncle to look after and care for him in place of his absentee ass-hat father, and was brought up (to some degree) with his brother and sister..

[image]

Naruto was an only child, though; neither he, nor his parents, had any siblings, which explains why he had no relatives to care for him as Gaara did. (Yes, self same relative tried to *kill him* when he was about 6, causing severe trauma and psychosis, but we know at least Yashamaru was *raising* the kid with *some* care for a while.)

Now, to be clear, it *is* implied that the Hokage Sarutobi *did* give some personal attention to Naruto's protection, and some type of orders that the child be sheltered fed, clothed and cared for in the absence of his parents. But...

**Who exactly was it that actually TOOK CARE of Naruto from the night he was born?**

Was he kept in the Konoha Little Lost saplings orphanage?

Did he have a wet nurse, or a special ANBU guardian to change his nappies?

Did the Hokage have special subordinates come into his apartment and just "babysit" on shifts until he was 5 or 6?

We saw he was living alone by the time he was 10, so he was obviously reasonably self sufficient... but *who taught him* the basic skills he needed to take care of himself, let alone how to read, right, and feed himself?

**Basically:** Is there any canon answer as to how Naruto managed to get from newborn to 10-year old without any family, friends, God parents or guardian watching over him?

And if there *was* someone/some team, in story, that was tasked with his care, what happened to them and why were thy nowhere to be seen in the story after it begins?

I'm aware that their are novels about the Uchiha and some supplementary books which better"flesh out" details from the "past" of the characters, so they pretty much fit into canon; answer from these, the manga, author's notes or even "filler" anime or special films would all be appreciated.

Comment: Related: (Anime & Manga SE) [Who took care of Naruto when he was young?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7596/310)

Comment: Also, who taught him to run like a weirdo?

Comment: @Valorum Actually, that seems to be a Ninja world standard. There's actually a proposed explanation for it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uSium6e6suE